# slow scroll in ssh connection after a while (why?)

Tags: linux, ssh, display, terminal, scrolling

Remote server with screen. After some time any command with a lots of lines of output causes significant scroll lag.

It happens with different terminal emulators: konsole, xterm, lilyterm, lxterminal.

It never happens just after connection. Usually it takes about an hour or even more to mitigate.

Opening another copy of same or different terminal emulator or even a new tab in the same terminal and joining same screen over ssh works well. I can see instant scroll in one window/tab and dozens of seconds in another window for the same command like *dmesg* in the same screen window. If I detach screen, reconnect ssh and attach screen again in the same terminal and tab then it works good for some time and then problem repeats.

Comment: If you exit the ssh session, is scrolling still slow in that terminal window? How large is the scrollback buffer in these terminal windows?